# Image Cropping module

Tags: javascript, image, drupal, drupal-7, crop

Does anyone know if there's a decent image crop module around for Drupal 7?

I used http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop in Drupal 6 but it's still in beta (bugged) for Drupal 7.

Also i tried http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop but I think it's not really user friendly and still see some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [EPSA Crop](http://drupal.org/project/epsacrop) and I found it nice, clean and user friendly. I had 6.x version, but it should work on 7.x as I can see in their project page.